# How to disable trendline in plotly.express.line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, trendline, plotly-express

I am willing to plot 3 timeseries on the same chart. Datasource is a `pandas.DataFrame()` object, the type of `Timestamp` being `datetime.date`, and the 3 different time series drawn from the same column `Value` using the color argument of `plotly.express.line()`.

The 3 lines show on the chart, but each one is accompanied by some sort of trendline. **I can't see in the function signature how to disable those trendlines. Can you please help?**

I have made several attempts, e.g. using another `color`, but the trendlines just stay there.

Please find below the code snippet and the resulting chart.

```
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.express as px
pio.renderers = 'jupyterlab'
fig = px.line(data_frame=df, x='Timestamp', y='Value', color='Position_Type')
fig.show()
```

(If relevant, I am using `jupyterlab`)

[image: scatterplot screenshot]

Timestamp on the screen appears like this (this are [regular] weekly timeseries) :

[image: soybeans time series data]

And, as per the type:

```
type(df.Timestamp[0])
> datetime.date
```

I am adding that it looks like the lines that I first thought were trendlines would rather be straight lines from the first datapoint to the last datapoint of each time series.

Comment: @tagoma Where's `value ` amd `POSITION_TYPE` in your data sample? You've used those in your `px.Scatter` setup.

Comment: thank you @vestland. the dataframe is quite large, i previously showed only the few first columns on the left. I edited my question to show 'Value' and 'Position_Type'.

Comment: If my suggestion helped you sort out your problem, would you consider marking it at as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 3):

```
df_melt = df_melt.sort_values('datetime_id')
```

Sorting got rid of those "wrap-arounds". Thanks for the suggestions above. Using Plotly 4.8.2.

Comment: Thanks, It helped my problem!

Answer (score 1):

**Introduction:**

Your provided data sample is an image, and not very easy to work with, so I'm going to use some sampled random time series to offer a suggestion. The variables in your datasample don't match the ones you've used in `px.Scatter` either by the way.

I'm on plotly version `'4.2.0'` and unable to reproduce your issue. Hopefully you'll find this suggestion useful anyway.

**Using data structured like this...**

```
     Timestamp Position_type      value
145 2020-02-15        value3  86.418593
146 2020-02-16        value3  78.285128
147 2020-02-17        value3  79.665202
148 2020-02-18        value3  84.502445
149 2020-02-19        value3  91.287312
```

**...I'm able to produce this plot...**

[image]

**...using this code:**

```
# imports
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data
np.random.seed(123)
frame_rows = 50
n_plots = 2
frame_columns = ['V_'+str(e) for e in list(range(n_plots+1))]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(-10,10,size=(frame_rows, len(frame_columns))),
                  index=pd.date_range('1/1/2020', periods=frame_rows),
                    columns=frame_columns)
df=df.cumsum()+100
df.iloc[0]=100
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df.columns=['Timestamp','value1', 'value2', 'value3' ]
varNames=df.columns[1:]


# melt dataframe with timeseries from wide to long format.
# YOUR dataset seems to be organized in a long format since
# you're able to set color using a variable name
df_long = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Timestamp'], value_vars=varNames, var_name='Position_type', value_name='value')
#df_long.tail()

# plotly time
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.express as px
#pio.renderers = 'jupyterlab'
fig = px.scatter(data_frame=df_long, x='Timestamp', y='value', color='Position_type')
#fig = px.line(data_frame=df_long, x='Timestamp', y='value', color='Position_type')
fig.show()
```

**If you change...**

```
 px.scatter(data_frame=df_long, x='Timestamp', y='value', color='Position_type')
```

**...to...**

```
fig = px.line(data_frame=df_long, x='Timestamp', y='value', color='Position_type')
```

**...you'll get this plot instead:**

No trendlines as far as the eye can see.

[image]

**Edit - I think I know what's going on...**

Having taken a closer look at your figure, I've realized that those lines are not trendlines. A trendline doesn't normally start at the initial value of a series and end up at the last value of the series. And that's what happening here for all three series. So I think you've got some bad or duplicate timestamps somewhere.

Comment: thank you @vestland. I apologize in the code above I mean 'line' instead of scatter (copy/paste issue).  your example code works just fine, but the issue remains with my original dataframe. i'm going to dig further.

Comment: go here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203666/room-for-vestland-and-tagoma

Comment: It works after I use the Timestamp column as index and plot the lines using this index.